# How can I logon to another machine when opening a new terminal, without causing the process to start looping?

Tags: ssh, redhat-enterprise-linux

So, when we login to the Red Hat machine we normally develop on, we have to go via another machine due to security reasons. The idea I had was to create an rsa key and connect to the next machine using ssh. I did this in the .cshrc.user file. However, what I did not think of was that the machines share my home drive. This causes the current procedure would create a loop which is not what I want. Do anyone have any ideas how to proceed?

Comment: Pretty easy: just check the value of the output of hostname (or the variable HOSTNAME if it exists in your default shell) and start ssh only if it contains the nam of your intermediate machine.

Comment: @GombaiSándor that is how I have solved it now. However, in some environments we have clustered machines, where I get routed to the "best" host. That would make it a bit annoying to solve it like this.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand right, you to go from A (your machine) to C throught B.

So you can try run this command from A.

```
ssh -A -t ServerB ssh -A -t serverC
```

If like the thinks more easy and transparent, you can configure [ssh ProxyCommand](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-ssh-proxycommand-passing-through-one-host-gateway-server/).

Comment: The problem is that my own machine is a laptop and runs windows 7. I connect to the remote servers using NoMachine (mandatory). The problem is that when I add the ssh to the .cshrc.user file it will start looping. All machines is connected to the same home drive and this means that every time I open a new terminal I do ssh, but when ssh connect to the next server it will run .cshrc.user as well. The server I normally use is not a cluster (which means I do not get routed to another server in the cluser), but a single server. So a condition in the .cshrc.user file will work in most cases.